# Google Analytics: I can't see any sessions for my site but I see real-time data

Tags: session, google-analytics, real-time

I added GA to my site about 14 hours ago, and have been visiting the site with different platforms and IP's. Still haven't see any data populated for sessions, or any data populated for the Audience tab in GA. But when I head over to the real-time tab in GA while I'm connected to my site, I see that GA is tracking me and looking at my page-views.

Is there something wrong or how long does it take for sessions to take effect (it's been 14 hours since my first connect)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For brand new accounts or properties, it usually takes about 24 hours to see data.

This usually *also* applies to Real Time data, so it's strange you're seeing that already, but I wouldn't worry about it unless you're still not seeing data tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah it took about 48 hours, sessions is now populated.